# Dropdownlist in Gridview not populating during Edit Mode

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have an asp gridview that i am wanting to populate a dropdownlist control when the selected row switches to edit mode.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFormatID" runat="server">
      </asp:DropDownList>
```

I'v googled around and i know you're suppose to do this at the rowdatabound and then check if the row is the one being edited, if so then populate the DDL but i can't get the check for the row to work properly :(

```
        If DataControlRowState.Edit = e.Row.RowState Then

        Dim ddlFormat As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("ddlFormatID")
        ddlFormat.DataSource = XRefBCWorker.GetFormatCombos
        ddlFormat.DataTextField = "Format"
        ddlFormat.DataValueField = "FormatID"
        ddlFormat.DataBind()

    End If
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try doing it in the GridView's RowEditing Event. Also check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms178294.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find this article and i changed my code in the rowdatabound event and it worked!

```
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If e.Row.DataItem IsNot Nothing Then
            If (e.Row.RowState And DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0 Then
                Dim ddlFormat As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("ddlFormatID")
                ddlFormat.DataSource = XRefBCWorker.GetFormatCombos
                ddlFormat.DataTextField = "Format"
                ddlFormat.DataValueField = "FormatID"
                ddlFormat.DataBind()
                ddlFormat.SelectedIndex = CurrentFormatID
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: I'm glad that you figure out. I'm wondering how you get CurrentFormatID?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast DataItem to a type that you display.

```
Protected Sub GridView_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If DataControlRowState.Edit = e.Row.RowState Then
        Dim item = e.Row.DataItem
        Dim dr = DirectCast(item, DataRowView)
        Dim id = Integer.Parse(dr(0).ToString())
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it in the markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList SelectedValue='<%# Bind("categoryId") %>'
```